# SQL Server Powershell Error: Invoke-SqlCmd Command cannot be found on this machine

Tags: sql-server, powershell

When I try to run a powershell script I get the following error:

Invoke-SqlCmd Command cannot be found on this machine, please install the SQL Powershell tools

So in Powershell I run the following:

```
install-module sqlserver
update-module sqlserver
```

Both run fine. However when I rerun my script I still get the same error.

Any ideas on what I should try?

I have SQLServer 2014 and Powershell Version 5

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced this question with: [SQL Powershell Error: Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622914/sql-powershell-error-invoke-sqlcmd-the-term-invoke-sqlcmd-is-not-recognized)

The error message quoted above is a custom one from the script I was running not the one that is given in Powershell. The new question gives the correct error message.