# Invoke-Sqlcmd cmlet missing in Powershell core sqlserver module for linux

Tags: powershell-core

I am using latest version of Powershell core on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to query a sql server database using powershell's invoke-sqlcmd cmdlet. (Yes I have installed the sqlserver module)
I get an error which says that it cannot find the cmdlet. The command is there in windows powershell when I install the sqlserver module.
[Screenshot of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMfQZ.jpg)

Does invoke-sqlcmd only work on Windows? If yes,is there another way I can achieve the same result in powershell core.

Comment: Found the solution. Instead of using the Invoke-sqlcmd, I am using the plain sqlcmd inside the invoke-command. Thats working well.

Comment: would you elaborate on how you did that?

Comment: Since "sqlcmd" will still work in the server hosting the database. I went for the invoke-command cmdlet. inside the invoke-command I invoked the invoke-expression command and I passed the sqlcmd as a parameter to the invoke-expression cmdlet.

Comment: What like `Invoke-Command Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd -i ./dropDatabaseScript.sql"`?
Maybe you can put that as an answer? with more details?

Comment: Indeed above worked for me as well! I split it in four parts. I had a folder with multiple scripts i wanted to run
`$files = "./*.sql";`
`$command = 'sqlcmd -i $_';`(also added dbname/user/psw and such)
`$expression = { Invoke-Expression $command };`
`Resolve-Path $files | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $expression};`

Answer (score 6):

With Powershell core (6.2.3 at the time of this writing), you can install the sql server module like so:

`Install-Module -Name SqlServer`

and then you can call `invoke-sqlcmd`

If you want to know more about it: http://sqlvariant.com/2019/03/invoke-sqlcmd-is-now-available-cross-platform-in-the-sqlserver-module/

Comment: This also worked for me running PowerShell Core on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell Core, the `sqlserver` module doesn't export any of the `Invoke-*` cmdlets. However, there are the `Read-SQLTableData` and `Read-SQLViewData` cmdlets that appear to work in a similar fashion if you've already created views on the server side.

Comment: Seems it has since been fixed and available